# How do I modify the Node.js package.json file depending on the environment i'm in?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to change the start script in package.json depending on the environment i'm in:

e.g, i'd like this in development:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
},
```

...and this in production:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "forever -a start ./server.js"
},
```

Is it possible for package.json to read environment variables? Then I could just throw that string into one of those...

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a script `start.js`, update the package.json to run `node start.js` and in that file you can check the variables and spawn a different command based on the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an environment variable ?

Something like:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "if [ -z "$ENV_PROD" ]; then forever -a start ./server.js; else node app.js; fi"
},
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing:        "start": "if [ -z \"$NODE_ENV\" == \"production\" ]; then forever -a start ./server.js; else node server.js; fi"

Comment: what's fi at the end for? do I need it?